# display directed graph on console

Tags: python, c, terminal, pretty-print, directed-graph

I am writing code to execute on a linux server that I connect to using SSH. I have only the console, and not a GUI to the server. I am trying to store a directed graph and then display it on the screen. I am open to using both C and python.

I can find several resources and libraries online that can help me print a graph on a graphical screen. However I am particularly looking to ASCII-print the graph, or at least come as close to displaying the graph in a human friendly way as possible.

What is the easiest known way to do this? It looks like a really unusual thing to do, considering how much help is available online.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have to use python, I think you should check out this perl library http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/output.html

It seems to be able to do what you need